# Tapping on a contact makes call, how can I see a contact's phone number on Android 8?

Tags: contacts, 8.0-oreo, phone-app

If I search for and tap a contact, it calls them, but I can't see their number. If I scroll up and down endlessly looking for a specific contact and I tap them, it still won't show me the phone number. Sometimes I would like to get a contact's number to share with someone else without having to call the contact first. Is this possible on Android 8?

I'm just using the stock dialer.

Comment: Which phone are you using? It sounds like the dialer app you have is not the one packaged with android by default, but one modified by your manufacturer. Every phone is different, so it's helpful to know which one we're working with.

Answer (score 1):

In stock Phone app (*com.android.dialer*), you can tap on the picture (extreme left) of the contact. It'll show the details of the contact, won't make a call.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to accept your answer, as your solution addressed the problem I had, but there is no check mark visible.

Comment: @dcacat follow this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @dcacat it seems you accidentally created 2 accounts. Please follow [this help center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to get access to your old account and the ownership of this post. Thank you.